# Ajax with PHP Security Concern

Tags: ajax, security, web

We have an application that has a lot of forms for submitting data. The forms make heavy use of AJAX with JSON for posting information to the database. I'm concerned about events where a malicious user may try to call our Ajax interface by passing JSON structured data. The php script would not differentiate between our own server calling it or the call being made from outside. In theory, the malicious user can write content in our database without going through our website. Is this a valid concern and if so, are there ways to tackle this ?

Comment: Force users to log in via PHP sessions. Enable SSL/TLS so no one can eavesdrop (Godaddy sometimes has specials on certificates for 10,20,30 dollars). If your server has a static IP address, make sure the script always checks the IP.

Comment: Good tips, I am already checking the IP, but I'm worried about how easy it is to spoof IP addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a valid concern.  OWASP has some good guidelines **[here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_AJAX_Security_Guidelines)** that you should read.

I would like to stress that you
**shouldn't rely on client logic**.

Answer (score 1):

HTTPS (HTTP through SSL/TLC) is what you want. The protocol will deal with server authentication and (optional) client authentication. You just need enable it in your server, you will be protected from man in the middle attack.